# Coloring specific links in a dendrogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

In a dendrogram from a hierarchical clustering in scipy, I would like to highlight links connecting specific two labels, let's say 0 and 1.

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hac
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

clustering = hac.linkage(points, method='single', metric='cosine')
link_colors = ["black"] * (2 * len(points) - 1)
hac.dendrogram(clustering, link_color_func=lambda k: link_colors[k])
plt.show()
```

The clustering has the following format:
`clustering[i]` corresponds to node number `len(points) + i` and its first two numbers are indices of nodes that are linked. Nodes with indices smaller than `len(points)` correspond to original `points`, higher indices to the clusters.

When drawing the dendrogram, different indexing of the links is used and these are the indices that are used for choosing the color. How do the indices of the links (as indexed in `link_colors`) correspond to indices in `clustering`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been very close to the solution. The indices in `clustering` are sorted by size of the 3rd columns of the `clustering` array. The indices of the color list for `link_color_func` are indices of `clustering` + the length of `points`.

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hac
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Sample data
points = np.array([[8, 7, 7, 1], 
            [8, 4, 7, 0], 
            [4, 0, 6, 4], 
            [2, 4, 6, 3], 
            [3, 7, 8, 5]])

clustering = hac.linkage(points, method='single', metric='cosine')
```

`clustering` does look like this

```
array([[3.        , 4.        , 0.00766939, 2.        ],
       [0.        , 1.        , 0.02763245, 2.        ],
       [5.        , 6.        , 0.13433008, 4.        ],
       [2.        , 7.        , 0.15768043, 5.        ]])
```

As you can see the ordering (and thus the row-index) results from `clustering` being sorted by the third column.

To highlight now a specific link (e.g. [0,1] as you proposed) you have to find the row index of the pair [0,1] within `clustering` and add `len(points)`. The resulting number is the index of the color list provided for `link_color_func`.

```
# Initialize the link_colors list with 'black' (as you did already)
link_colors = ['black'] * (2 * len(points) - 1)
# Specify link you want to have highlighted
link_highlight = (0, 1)
# Find index in clustering where first two columns are equal to link_highlight. This will cause an exception if you look for a link, which is not in clustering (e.g. [0,4])
index_highlight = np.where((clustering[:,0] == link_highlight[0]) * 
                           (clustering[:,1] == link_highlight[1]))[0][0]
# Index in color_list of desired link is index from clustering + length of points
link_colors[index_highlight + len(points)] = 'red'

hac.dendrogram(clustering, link_color_func=lambda k: link_colors[k])
plt.show()
```

Like this, you can highlight the desired link:

[image]

It works also for links between an original element and a cluster or between two clusters (e.g. `link_highlight = (5, 6)`)

[image]